# Will the Lenovo x230 work with DDR3-1866?

Tags: memory, thinkpad, ddr

What is the max clock speed of the DDR3 that the x230 can run. I don't see it on Lenovo.com. Is it 1866mhz or 1600mhz? [I see they don't sell 1866mhz](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/x-series/x230/) as an upgrade, but I don't believe that means it won't work.

Comment: Doesn't matter the memory will down clock.  Just be sure you do it by hand if it's not automatic also check what you currently have installed

Comment: the mainstream Ivy Bridge cpus only support DDR1600. Why do you want to use 1866?

Comment: And is he Lenovo x230 a "mainstream Ivy Bridge"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evan

[Acc to Lenovo](http://shop.lenovo.com/ISS_Static/WW/wci/products/us/laptop/thinkpad/x-series/x230/X230-datasheet.pdf) 1600MHz is the max memory speed and some other sites also stick with 1600MHz like this site - [Click here!!](http://www.memorystock.com/memory/IBMThinkPadX230.html)As of now 1600MHz is the perfect speed for current generation of laptops and would be better to stick with it. Moreover, all the supported CPU's have a FSB of 1600MHz or lower.

Theoretically, DDR3-1866 should work but pratically it may or may not and also depends on your CPU. Even if the memory works, the memory will be downclocked to 1600MHz and I do not believe there is too much option in the bios to manually tweak the settings either. IMO, it is a gamble but there are sites like Crucial which guarantee it will work so contact them.

Good luck mate!! Hope your gamble pays off and if it does, make sure to post the results for other users!! :-)